# How to send the progress when using Parallel.ForEach

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, parallel-extensions

I am planning to use Parallel.ForEach on a DataTable so that each record can be written to a file.

How can we notify user the percentage/number of records that are processed.

Normally when we use Background worker we have a ProgressChanged event where the user is notified on the percentage of work done. How can we achieve this using Parallel.ForEach or Multiple tasks?

Thanks, Bunny

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need a (shared) counter that starts at 0 and that you increment (with Interlocked) at the *end* of each part.

And then you need to

1. trigger an event, and the event has to use Invoke (or Dispatch)
2. or have a Timer periodically sample the counter

Option 2) is easier and much more efficient when the number of iterations is large.

Comment: When I use Timer(System.Timers.Timer it throws an exception. Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

Comment: @bonny: Use a WinForms timer. It is already synced to the GUI.

Comment: @Henk. It seems the timer thread is blocked until the Parallel.ForEach is completed. I am using WinForms timer for every 5 sec. The timer is updated only after Parallel.ForEach is completed. I am not able to update the progress to the UI until it Parallel.ForEach finishes processing.

Comment: @bunny: that could be the case if you run the ForEach from the main thread. You would be blocking your GUI then. Use a Bgw, or create tasks from a regular `foreach`

Comment: @Henk. The application is working like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

I have had a similar issue. What we did to solve it was to use [`Interlocked.Increment`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z791w8a.aspx) on a number that was visible to all the threads and the UI and shown the progress bar based off of that.

EDIT:
note that if you your counter is a `long` you will need to use [`Interlocked.Read`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read.aspx) to read it. if you are using a int the process is already atomic.